# Porto theme product page is not working on php 7.2 / Magento 2

Tags: magento2, porto-theme

Hello I get the following error on the products pages with PHP 7.2 , Magento 2.33

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /chroot/home/ae393a83/xxxxxxxx.com/app/code/Smartwave/Porto/Helper/Customtabs.php on line 74
```

Thanks
Martin

Comment: you should update / patch your Porto theme to the latest version that supports M2.3.3

Comment: Sorry - the latest had the bug in it @paj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Way..:

```
if ( count( $cms_tabs )) {
....
}
```

> Add "`is_array($cms_tabs) &&`" to become:

```
if (is_array($cms_tabs) && count($cms_tabs) ) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution.

Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Porto -> Porto - Settings Panel -> Product View -> Product Custom Tabs.

In that section I add and delete for Product Custom Static Block Tabs and Product Custom Attribute Tabs. I leave them with 0 rows and saved. Cleared the cache and now works.